# Crontab not executing a Python script on my Mac?

Tags: python, macos, cron, schedule

I can run this in my terminal
/Users/quintus/opt/anaconda3/bin/python /Users/quintus/Desktop/python/04_Jobs/Jobs.py

However, I can not set up my crontab, I type
48 23 * * * /Users/quintus/opt/anaconda3/bin/python /Users/quintus/Desktop/python/04_Jobs/Jobs.py

I read similar questions but haven't found solution.

Comment: Can you start other programs with `crontab`?

Comment: You're probably running into privacy protection on the /Users/quintus/Desktop/ folder (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64419734/macos-catalina-launchd-cant-open-input-file-error/)). There may also be problems due to the minimal environment cron jobs run with, but without troubleshooting on your part it's impossible to tell. Have you tried capturing output & errors from the job in log files?

Answer (score 1):

I have not worked on my Mac in a while, but I just logged in to test this. If you try the following it might work:

```
48 23 * * * python3 /Users/quintus/Desktop/python/04_Jobs/Jobs.py
```

That would get the script to run in Python 3.x and if you want to use Python 2.x just replace python3 with python. I migh
t have done something extra to get python3 command to work, but if that is the case it was much too long ago.

Also, this will run every 48 hours and 23 min. I just want to point that out because it seems very odd timing.

Comment: At 23:48 each day I presume.